# Ionic 2 implement Scrollable Div in side ion-content diractive

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

*This is a answer not question but I don't know how to post a answer here.*

After seeing [some articles](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/) for the same I came to know that-
The ionContent directive provides an easy to use content area that can be configured to use Ionic’s custom Scroll View.

In my case,
Wanted to scroll a specific division inside the *`<ion-contain>`* such as-

```
<ion-content>
       <div>
            <div>
              <p> Scroll should not be apply </p>
           </div>
       </div>

    <div *ngFor="let item in items">
             <div>
              <p> Scroll **should be apply** </p>  
                {{item}}
           </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

1. I came to know about [VirtualScroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/), but It was being scrolling complete page which was not matching with my requirement.
2. Also came to see [Scroll property](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/scroll/Scroll/) of ionic, which does not meet to my requirement.

Then I came to see a great Article listed under ionic forum and helped me a lot which is as-
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-scrollable-div-within-ion-content/58788

```
<ion-content style="overflow-y: hidden;">
    <div>
        <h1>This stuff should not scroll.</h1>
    </div>

    <ion-scroll scrollY="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div *ngFor="let boy in boys">
            <h3>This stuff should scroll.</h3>
    </div>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

[Here was the required above code.](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-scrollable-div-within-ion-content/58788/2) which help me a lot.
Very thank full for this to the author of this article (asrinivasan).

***Note:- I came to notice -*

*If we have ion-item tag in our code, it could cause some issue for us. So make sure to remove this tag.***

Comment: to share your knowledge. Ask a question and **check the checkbox Answer your question** and give your answer. Happy that you want to contribute to the community!!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it almost worked. I did exactly same as above, but still one issue. If you scroll down to `ion-scroll` area, the top `should not scroll` area would disappear, became part of scrollable content

Comment: You have to fix height of that div, did you?