# How to make a static ion-list scrollable in ionic?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3, ion-list

I have a static list in ionic and i need only the list part to be scrollable. I already tried this
[stack overflow question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462043/ionic-2-implement-scrollable-div-in-side-ion-content-diractive) but it does'nt work for me.

It says that- **If we have ion-item tag in our code, it could cause some issue for us. So make sure to remove this tag** . I don't know whether it is because of that. No matter what i do, i can only get the whole content to be scrollable or no scroll at all. I want only the list part mentioned below to be scrollable.

Here is my code :

```
 <ion-content class="calendar-page ">
  <div class="calendar-section" padding>
    <ion-calendar #calendar></ion-calendar>
  </div>


  <div class="reminder-section ">
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-assertive section-title mt-20">
      <h2 class="title" align="center">Reminders</h2>
    </div>

    **//scrollable from here**

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="custom-font-size">
        QUIT SMOKING<span item-end>Today, 14:00</span>
        <ion-icon name="alarm" class="alarm-icon-color" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>


      <ion-item class="custom-font-size">
        GET FIT<span item-end>Today, 18:00</span>
        <ion-icon name="alarm" class="alarm-icon-color" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item class="custom-font-size">
        QUIT SMOKING<span item-end>11 MAY 2018, 08:00</span>
        <ion-icon name="alarm" class="alarm-icon-color" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="custom-font-size">
        QUIT SMOKING<span item-end>10 MAY 2018, 11:00</span>
        <ion-icon name="alarm" class="alarm-icon-color" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="custom-font-size">
        GET FIT<span item-end>8 MAY 2018, 10:12</span>
        <ion-icon name="alarm" class="alarm-icon-color" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    **// scrollable till here**

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

I am using ionic 3.

Comment: Did u try `<ion-scroll>` go through  this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/) might help your case.

Comment: @NRaghavendra I have already tried adding that. When i try putting my list inside <ion-scroll scrollY="true"> </ion-scroll> the entire list dissapears.

Comment: for <ion-scroll> you have to give height attribute in css or programatically, probably you missed that.

Comment: @NRaghavendra I had tried setting the height inline as well as in css. That dint solve the issue.

Comment: please go through demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-y3y58x?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: @NRaghavendra Thank You this fixed my issue.

Comment: @NRaghavendra if you can post this as an answer I will mark and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try below link for scroll-able list
```

https://codepen.io/KevinWang15/pen/QNJEXX

Comment: None of the components in this is scrollable at all, everything is fixed only. Plz, recheck what you have posted.

Comment: I have verified and then posted a link. Please check the scrollable list at the bottom,  it is scrollable and check the code also. Please verify once.

Comment: Sorry i saw the scroll part, but i could'nt figure out much from the css part. You are note defining scroll, overflow or anything anywhere. It works in your example but its too css much for my small issue.  [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-y3y58x?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)  solves the issue in two lines, may be you can also refer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution as suggested by @NRaghavendra

```
<ion-scroll scrollY="true" style="height: 200px">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="custom-font-size">
        QUIT SMOKING<span item-end>Today, 14:00</span>
        <ion-icon name="alarm" class="alarm-icon-color" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>


      <ion-item class="custom-font-size">
        GET FIT<span item-end>Today, 18:00</span>
        <ion-icon name="alarm" class="alarm-icon-color" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item class="custom-font-size">
        QUIT SMOKING<span item-end>11 MAY 2018, 08:00</span>
        <ion-icon name="alarm" class="alarm-icon-color" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="custom-font-size">
        QUIT SMOKING<span item-end>10 MAY 2018, 11:00</span>
        <ion-icon name="alarm" class="alarm-icon-color" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="custom-font-size">
        GET FIT<span item-end>8 MAY 2018, 10:12</span>
        <ion-icon name="alarm" class="alarm-icon-color" item-end></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-scroll>
```